# Plotting the score matrix from a Needleman-Wunsch pairwise sequence alignment in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bioinformatics, biopython

I'm trying to draw a matrix according to global alignment algorithm (or [Needleman–Wunsch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm)) in Python.

I don't know if matplotlib is the best tool for this case. I tried to use [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) but the structure was so difficult to fit a matrix as I wanted.

I'm using [Bio.SeqIO](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO) (the standard Sequence Input/Output interface for BioPython) to store two sequences.

I what to get a result similar to this image:

[image]

Is that possible in Matplotlib? How can I do that?

**UPDATE**

Finally I was able to construct the algorithm from the answer given by ImportanceOfBeingErnest. Here is the result:

[image]

Here is the gist for this implementation: [plot_needleman_wunsch.py](https://gist.github.com/kevinah95/f6f9d16ebd17a3a28208471f4e4bb878)

And here is the whole project (Work in progress): [bmc-sequence-alignment](https://github.com/kevinah95/bmc-sequence-alignment)

Comment: if you add your two sequences of data, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: `seq_alpha = Seq("GATCCA")` and `seq_beta = Seq("GTGCCT")`

Comment: sorry I'm not a biostats guy. can you reproduce where the numbers and arrows (color and direction) come from? matplotlib definitely doesn't have something built in to figure that out. but if you can provide that, I can try to plot this

Comment: I'm not a biostats either, but I'm going to try to explain with examples. The colors of the arrows do not interest me, but the directions. To understand where the arrows come from please read the sections **3.1.1** and **3.1.2** from this [tutorial](http://etutorials.org/Misc/blast/Part+II+Theory/Chapter+3.+Sequence+Alignment/3.1+Global+Alignment+Needleman-Wunsch/). Briefly, I have two arrays of size m and n. The matrix is ​​(m + 1 x n + 1). Then fill the first row and the first column with "gaps". And to get the directions ask what is the maximum value between the diagonal, the left and up

Comment: "To understand where the arrows come from please read the sections 3.1.1 and 3.1.2 from this tutorial." I'm not interested in reading up on how to reproduce your data. If you provided the data you wanted plotted, someone would probably plot it for you.

Comment: Ok, you are right. Maybe you know how to do this: I draw an arrow diagonally horizontally or vertically from the number that is in the middle of the cell. I tried to do it, but I did not succeed. This is my try: http://imgur.com/wI1pS5Q

Comment: if you made that imgur plot with matplotlib, you should post that code, along with the data used to generate it. although the arrows have no color and the cell values are 0/X instead of numbers like your first plot, so it still wouldn't be enough to reproduce the original plot you said you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no clear description of the algorithm to place the arrows in the question; therefore this answer focusses on the way to procude a similar plot in matplotlib.

[image]

The idea here is to place the numbers at integer positions in the plot and draw minor gridlines at `n+0.5` to obtain the table-like appearance. The arrows are drawn as annotations between positions defined in a 4-column array (first 2 column: x and y of the start of the arrow, third and fourth column: x,y of arrow's end).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np;np.random.seed(5)
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = 4,5
param = {"grid.linewidth" : 1.6,
         "grid.color"     : "lightgray",
         "axes.linewidth" : 1.6,
         "axes.edgecolor" : "lightgray"}
plt.rcParams.update(param)

#Data
headh = list("GATCCA")
headv = list("GTGCCT")

v = np.zeros((7,7), dtype=int)
v[1:,1:] = np.random.randint(-2,7, size=(6,6))

arrows = np.random.randint(0,v.shape[1], size=(14,4))
opt = np.array([(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)])
arrows[:,2:] = arrows[:,:2] + opt[np.random.randint(0,3,size=14 )]

arrowsb = np.random.randint(0,v.shape[1], size=(7,4))
optb = np.array([(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)])
arrowsb[:,2:] = arrowsb[:,:2] + optb[np.random.randint(0,3,size=7 )]

#Plot
fig, ax=plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(-1.5, v.shape[1]-.5 )
ax.set_ylim(-1.5, v.shape[0]-.5 )
ax.invert_yaxis()
for i in range(v.shape[0]):
    for j in range(v.shape[1]):
        ax.text(j,i,v[i,j], ha="center", va="center")
for i, l in enumerate(headh):
    ax.text(i+1,-1,l, ha="center", va="center", fontweight="semibold")
for i, l in enumerate(headv):
    ax.text(-1,i+1,l, ha="center", va="center", fontweight="semibold")

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(np.arange(-1.5, v.shape[1]-.5,1)))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(np.arange(-1.5, v.shape[1]-.5,1)))
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', bottom='off', top='off', 
                left="off", right="off", labelbottom='off', labelleft='off')
ax.grid(True, which='minor')


arrowprops=dict(facecolor='crimson',alpha=0.5, lw=0, 
                shrink=0.2,width=2, headwidth=7,headlength=7)
for i in range(arrows.shape[0]):
    ax.annotate("", xy=arrows[i,2:], xytext=arrows[i,:2], arrowprops=arrowprops)
arrowprops.update(facecolor='blue')
for i in range(arrowsb.shape[0]):
    ax.annotate("", xy=arrowsb[i,2:], xytext=arrowsb[i,:2], arrowprops=arrowprops)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks a lot! That's what I wanted. I'll upload the update with the solution that fits the algorithm. Thank you again.